# OpenCV capture doesn't work gets this problem MFVideoFormat_RGB24(codec not found),how can i solve?

Tags: python, opencv, codec

I am making a python app i need openCV library here is my code:

```
# importing the required modules
import cv2
import numpy as np

# capturing from the first camera attached
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# will continue to capture until 'q' key is pressed
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    # Program will terminate when 'q' key is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
        break

# Releasing all the resources
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

when I run the code I got this error:

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wwma2wne\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (677) CvCapture_MSMF::initStream Failed to set mediaType (stream 0, (640x480 @ 30) MFVideoFormat_RGB24(codec not found)
```

I think may be it requires a codec driver but i don't know how to fix the error
please help me friends

Answer (score 2):

following code resolved this issue for me: `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)`

Answer (score 1):

try

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)